# How Can I Convert JAXB to JSON?

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, jaxb

I need to create a web service front-end to an XML-based web service that returns a JAXB object.  My front-end needs to return a RESTful format.  Is there a way to convert that to JSON?  I have **jackson-mapper-asl** and **jackson-core-asl** in my class path.

As a simple test, I return a bean of Book, and it gets output as JSON, but the JAXB object (delivery schedule) stays in an XML format.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class DSWLIClient {

    @Autowired
    private DeliveryScheduleWS wliService;
    private BookService bs;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/DSDetails/{ds-number}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    DeliverySchedule getDSDetails(@PathVariable("ds-number") String dsNumber) {
        DeliveryScheduleResponse dsDetails = wliService.getDeliveryScheduleWSSoap().getDSDetails(dsNumber);
        DeliverySchedule deliverySchedule = dsDetails.getDeliverySchedule();
        return deliverySchedule;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/BookDetails/{isbn-number}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    Book getBookDetails(@PathVariable("isbn-number") String isbnNumber) {
        bs = new BookService();
        Book b = bs.getBookByIsbn(isbnNumber);
        System.out.println(b.getAuthor());
        return b;
    }


}
```

Comment: You simple need add @Produces("application/xml") or headers section with content similar to this: headers = {Const.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON} to your @RequestMapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show your configuration file (XML or class)?

Also I will assume that you are using the HttpMessageConverter (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-restful/) class and not the ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.

That is dead easy, most of the time is because we forget to add the required configuration "mvc:annotation-driven"

In case you use the content negotiation view this example is great http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-contentnegotiatingviewresolver-example/

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have a Spring XML file, but the contents are all Spring-related (component-scan, and property-configurer).   I do have the following:

  <context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>